# JavaFx: Rendering 500k rectangles is very slow the 1.time, but fast afterwards. Why?

Tags: java, javafx, 2d, rendering

I am using JavaFx and Canvas to render a map as 500k colored rectangles. The 1.time I render them, it takes around 40 seconds, but later less than 1 second:

1.Time:

```
10:11:17:133 INFO jfws.util.map.MapRenderer - render()
10:11:54:469 INFO jfws.editor.map.MapEditorController - render(): Finished
```

Later:

```
10:40:23:905 INFO jfws.util.map.MapRenderer - render()
10:40:23:989 INFO jfws.editor.map.MapEditorController - render(): Finished
```

The code contains 2 loops with 2 commands per rectangle:

```
graphicsContext.setFill(color);
graphicsContext.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

See [MapRenderer.java](https://github.com/Orchaldir/FantasyWorldSimulation/blob/master/FantasyWorldSimulation/src/jfws/util/map/MapRenderer.java).

I am also rendering a small map with 200 rectangles many times before that without any problems.

Comment: it's due to the cache. When you open something, you load many abojet, but when you close it, some data stay il your computer to load faster.

Comment: Even if I modify part of the map (~5k rectangles), it still renders the whole 500k in less than a second.

Comment: What hapen if thé first tome you load 1 rectangle ?

Comment: An loading a different map, which changes the color of every rectangle is equally fast.

Comment: The application starts with rendering a map with 200 rectangles. That happens very fast. Later it switches to the larger map and it slows down the 1.time rendering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer! :-D

I render the large map with PixelWriter into an WritableImage and then draw the image on the canvas. Now the rendering takes less than 1 second!

See [commit](https://github.com/Orchaldir/FantasyWorldSimulation/commit/c707ee9e5add8d95bc82c24728c275b0817e5bc1).